# Combobox Display items

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, combobox

Does the ItemsSource property not bind to the item?

XAML :

```
 <ComboBox  Name="cmbUserName" Height="30"  
          VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,64,614,0"/>

 <ComboBox Name="cmbAcessTime" Height="30"  
          VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="354,64,288,0"/>
```

C# :

```
DMSService.DMSService service = new DMSService.DMSService();
var logList = service.GetLogDetails();
var UserNames = (from A in logList orderby A.FirstName select new UserName { Users = A.FirstName + " " + A.SurName, ID = Convert.ToInt32(A.Id) }).Distinct();
var loginDate = (from A in logList select A.LogInTime.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)).Distinct();

cmbUserName.ItemsSource = UserNames;
cmbAccessDate.ItemsSource = loginDate;
```

[image]

I want to add these usernames in Combobox and set ID. Then, pass ID where combobox on change.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set ComboBox property SelectedValuePath and DisplayMemberPath from your datasource. Please check the below XAML:

```
    <ComboBox  Name="cmbUserName" Height="30"  
              VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,64,614,0"
              SelectedValuePath="Id" DisplayMemberPath="usernames" />

     <ComboBox Name="cmbAcessTime" Height="30"  
              VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="354,64,288,0"
              SelectedValuePath="Id" DisplayMemberPath="usernames" />
```

You can get selected value of ComboBox using the below code and pass value where you want.

```
var selectedHPQ = (int)cmbUserName.SelectionBoxItem;
```

Thanks

Comment: I have bind the comboBox like SelectedValuePath="Id" DisplayMemberPath="usernames" . But it is now showing empty list. UserNames variable contain linq result. How can I work this? Please look up on 1st image. The linq returning result like the image.